# Azure send error messages daily or when it occur

Tags: azure, cloud, azureportal

Do we have any built in feature/plugin in azure portal which sends error messages on daily basis? Or will connect to azure storage and send email messages to configured email ids? Can one suggest any pointer which can solve my purpose please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can receive an alert based on monitoring metrics for, or events on, your Azure services.

For an alert rule on a metric value, when the value of a specified metric crosses a threshold assigned, the alert rule becomes active and can send a notification. For an alert rule on events, a rule can send a notification on every event, or, only when a certain number of events happen.

When you create an alert rule, you can select options to send an email notification to the service administrator and co-administrators or to another administrator that you can specify. A notification email is sent when the rule becomes active, and when an alert condition is resolved.

You can set it from the portal and/or APIs as mentionned here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/insights-receive-alert-notifications/

Don't forget to mark as solved if it answered your question, thank you